# Trying to understand Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, textbook-erratum

**The Problem:**
So I was reading this book 
[Challenging Modern Physics: Questioning Einstein's Relativity Theories](http://www.bookpump.com/bwp/pdf-b/1124376b.pdf)
, and came across the concept of special relativity on pages 10 - 13. On page 13, I came across this[image]
But, I couldn't get my head around, the line

> The distance traveled by B is 2.5 light seconds

The closest I could get to understanding it is knowing that a clue lies in the fact that A is the observer, and he views B as parallel to him.

**The Question:**
Can you help me figure out how the author arrived at the conclusion that B travels at 2.5 light seconds?

**Disclaimer:**
This is in no way a homework question or likewise. This was my first attempt at actually understanding Special Relativity. If this is a possible duplicate of a question with an actual answer, please point me towards that direction. Thanks

**Note:**
This question is based on a book that challenges the credibility of Einstein's theory of Special Relativity, and I understand that the users of this site "know" that the theory has been verified, so it is possible that the writer's understanding "maybe" flawed.

Comment: I think you should point out that your question is based on a book that asserts that SR is not to be trusted as a theory. This is because SR has been experimentally verified and that most users of this site accept it as valid, unlike the writer of the  book cited above.

Comment: It would help if there was a question in your post. I see no "?" anywhere in the post, and am not certain what your question is. The light-second is a unit of distance, the distance light travels in one second.

Comment: @snarkyname77 : I don't have a problem understanding the units, but how the author arrived at the conclusion that B travels 2.5 light seconds. I just edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @FaraazAhmad your guess is as good as mine. Starting in the second paragraph there is a reference to a variable 't' which is not indicated in the photo copy provided. There isn't enough information provided for me or anyone else to comment specifically on your question. I would suggest starting with a university text book on physics, learn Special Relativity,  and then scrutinize the author's arguments for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the author is challenging in his argument, but I think the distance in question is the distance to B **as seen in the frame of A**, whereas the picture shows the point of view of a frame that observes both A and B as moving along the shown trajectories. So let us imagine what A sees:

To measure the distance to B, he (A) sends out the light signal at time $t_r$ and receives it back at time $t_s = t_r + 5s$. Then he waits $4s$ more until B finally arrives at his position at time $t_p = t_s + 4s$.

Therefore from A's point of view his light signal must have reached B at a distance $c(t_s - t_r)/2 = (2.5$ light seconds) away and B takes $\Delta t  = (t_s - t_r)/2 + (t_p - t_s) = 6.5s$ to follow the returning light signal to A's position, etc.